# how to check the speed between 2 switch hub

Tags: switch, ethernet, lan, speed, cable

I have 2 gigabit switch hub both have Green(for 1000 mbps) and Orange(for 100 mbps) indicator lights at each port. the distance between two gigabit switch hub is 100 meters. I use CAT5E outdoor cable.

The first hub switch connected to 4 IP camera(720p) and connect to the second hub switch(which is 100 meters away).

My concern is that the first switch hub will not be able to send data or has too many noise when it send data to the second switch hub.

How can I check wether the speed and stability between two switch hub will be enough for sending data of 4 cameras or not?

Can the light on the switch hub Green or Orange help me check that it will be ok or not?

I didn't buy the IP camera yet. I want to check the network first

I have attached the diagram with this question.

[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's either a hub or a switch.  They're not the same thing: switches use packet switching to determine who the recipient is and forward traffic on to that port only.  Hubs offer poorer performance, to say the least, because they repeat all incoming traffic they receive on one port to all the other ports without checking to see who actually wants the packets.

I would strongly encourage you to use switches if what you have now are actually hubs.  What are the model numbers?

You have already answered your own question about the speed.  Plug in your ethernet run to a device at each end and see what speed each hub/switch auto negotiates to.  The different LED colors are there to quickly check what speed a port is running at without having a computer handy- perfect for your needs.

Lastly,  have a look at [this IP camera bandwidth calculator.](http://www.stardot.com/bandwidth-and-storage-calculator)  It may help you decide if you need 1000 mbps.  You may easily get away with a 100 mbps network if all that's connected are the four cameras.  However, I would again encourage you to use switches instead of hubs.  In my experience, it will alleviate many problems and headaches before they even begin, and the price is essentially the same!